# ANTLR4 explain variable declaration error

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I am writing a parser and it is required that a variable declaration consists
of an identifier and an optional value initialization.
If the starting word is var, the value initialization is obligatory. It starting with an
assignment sign (<-) and an expression. The type of expression is assigned to variable at
the compile time. \

```
TRUE : 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
    //types
NUMBER: 'number';
BOOL: 'bool';
STRING: 'string';

RETURN: 'return';
VAR: 'var';
DYNAMIC: 'dynamic';
FUNC: 'func';
FOR: 'for';
UNTIL: 'until';
BY: 'by';
BREAK: 'break';
CONTINUE: 'continue';
IF: 'if';
ELSE: 'else';
ELIF: 'elif';
BEGIN: 'begin';
END: 'end';

/* LOGIC OPERATORS */
NOT: 'not';
AND: 'and';
OR: 'or';

/* ARITHMETIC OPERATORS */
// NEV: '-'; //overlap with SUB
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';
MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
MOD: '%';

/* STRING OPERATORS */
CONCAT : '...';

/* RELATIONAL OPERATORS */
EQ: '=';
NOT_EQ: '!=';
LT: '<';
GT: '>';
LTE: '<=';
GTE: '>=';
STRINGCMP: '=='; // Compare two same strings, STRING operand's type

ASSIGN          : '<-';

/* SEPERATORS */
R_OPEN: '('; //ROUND 
R_CLOSE: ')';
SQ_OPEN: '['; //SQUARE
SQ_CLOSE: ']';
C_OPEN: '{';  //CURLY
C_CLOSE: '}';
COMMA: ',';
SEMI: ';';



/* LITERAL */
// Fragment

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
fragment DECIMALPART : DIGIT* ('.' DIGIT | DIGIT '.') DIGIT*;
fragment INTEGER : DIGIT DIGIT*;
fragment EXPONENTPART : [eE] ([-+])? INTEGER;

NUMBER_LITERAL :  INTEGER EXPONENTPART? | DECIMALPART EXPONENTPART? ; 

/* IDENTIFIER */
ID: [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*;
// INT: [0-9]+;


literal: NUMBER_LITERAL | TRUE | FALSE  ;


program: NEWLINE* declare+  EOF;


declare: (var_decl | func_decl) NEWLINE+;
// All declarations and statements in this programming language
// must end with a newline character.
// Types
prim_type: NUMBER | BOOL | STRING;
//variable declaration
var_decl: (varDecl | arrayDecl  ) ;
func_decl: 'func declaration';
arrayDecl: 'array declaration';
varDecl: (DYNAMIC | prim_type) ID (ASSIGN (literal | ID))?
        | VAR ID ASSIGN (literal | ID)
        ;

// newline character
NEWLINE: '\n' | '\r\n';
/* COMMENT */
LINECMT : '##' ~[\n\r\f]* -> skip;

WS : [ \t\f\b]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
ERROR_CHAR: . {raise ErrorToken(self.text)};
```

The issue lies in the failed test case that I received.

```
def test_204(self):
            input = '''
var UyYv ## tv2xjibo,@
number u7i[6.385,406.606,76.243E39] <- 84.870E+57
'''
            expect = '''Error on line 2 col 23: 
'''
            self.assertTrue(TestParser.test(input, expect, 204))
```

whereas my solution is (include the empty line created by NEWLINE):

```
Error on line 2 col 22:
```

My solution got 2 newlines while it is expected to detect 1 new newline. And I don't know why?
I have been stuck on this for quite some time. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you update your question so that it include a complete grammar and clearly indicate on what input it fails? Right now, there are too many parts missing making other have to guess.

Comment: Well, for the partial input `var UyYv ## tv2xjibo,@` is tokenized as 'var', 'ID', NEWLINE. There is no way to parse a complete varDecl because you don't have an assignment at line 2 col 23. You have a NEWLINE instead. Print out all the tokens and verify you get what you want from the lexer. Then worry about the parse.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated the question

Comment: Print the tokens from the lexer! [@-1,0:0='\n',<49>,1:0]
[@-1,1:3='var',<9>,2:0]
[@-1,5:8='UyYv',<48>,2:4]
[@-1,23:23='\n',<49>,2:22]
[@-1,24:29='number',<5>,3:0]
[@-1,31:33='u7i',<48>,3:7]
[@-1,34:34='[',<41>,3:10]
[@-1,35:39='6.385',<47>,3:11]
[@-1,40:40=',',<45>,3:16]
[@-1,41:47='406.606',<47>,3:17]
[@-1,48:48=',',<45>,3:24]
[@-1,49:57='76.243E39',<47>,3:25]
[@-1,58:58=']',<42>,3:34]
[@-1,60:61='<-',<38>,3:36]
[@-1,63:72='84.870E+57',<47>,3:39]
[@-1,73:73='\n',<49>,3:49]
[@-1,74:73='<EOF>',<-1>,4:0]
line 2:22 mismatched input '\n' expecting '<-'
...

Comment: I copied your snippet of driver code and ran it on both Linux and Windows, with both "Dos" and "Unix" newline styles for the .py driver (convert using dos2unix or unix2dos), and I get *three* NEWLINE tokens `<49>`, not two nor one.

Comment: Do you know why this happened?

Comment: The first NEWLINE happens because you have in the input a triple-quoted string `'''` then a `\n`. In other words, line one is a blank line. The second NEWLINE happens because you have a COMMENT in line 2 of the input string. Note that COMMENT terminates before the `\n`, so the next token is NEWLINE. You next have a lone line of input for line 3, with another `\n` followed by the close triple quote `'''`. The lexer returns a NEWLINE for that last line.